# Is " Are there the person who have a doller?" grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality

A person said " Are there the person who have a doller?" would be grammatically incorrect. Is this true?

Answer (score 19):

I assume that you are speaking to a group of people and asking if anyone is willing to lend you a dollar. If that is the case, the sentence is both **ungrammatical** and **unidiomatic**.

Grammatically, there are three errors and one mis-spelling.

- The singular *person* calls for a singular verb at the beginning: ***Is*** there...
- The same noun also calls for a singular verb in the relative clause which modifies it: *...who **has**...*
- Since you are not speaking of a particular person but asking whether any of a number of people present has what you want, you should use the indefinite article: *Is there **a** person*...
- *Doll**a**r*, not *doll**e**r*

In any case, we don't ask this question this way. We say

> Does anybody have a dollar?  *OR*
>   Does someone have a dollar?

In this case, the inflection for person and number lies on the auxiliary *do*, and *have* is the infinitive form which *do* requires.

Comment: I agree with your suggested alternative, but note that it may be confusing to beginners in this context, since "have" is a plural verb form: the entire verb phrase here is "does have" which is singular, but that's not immediately obvious unless you go and parse the grammar.

Comment: @JasonS Good point; I have expanded.

Comment: *Grammatically*  there is a *misspelling*?

Comment: I'd use *anyone* there.

Comment: @TRiG What I'd *actually* say is "Anybody got a dollar?"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that sentence has a number of errors. If I understand the intent correctly, I would change it to:

> Is there someone who has a dollar?

There are a couple of aspects here (aside from spelling):

- You need to have [subject-verb agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_%28linguistics%29). If the subject ("the person" in your example, "someone" in mine) is singular, the verb form/forms ("Is" and "has") must be singular.
- You are asking a question and don't know who "the person" is. That's why you use "someone" instead. Anytime you use a definite article ("the") with a noun, it means you've already made it clear who or what you are referring to. This is called an [antecedent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_%28grammar%29), and you have to have it before you can use a definite article or pronoun. (You could say "Is there a person who has a dollar?" but this is less preferable.)

Comment: I don't like 'is there someone...' Really should be 'anyone' (or secondary, 'anybody', but that's unwieldy). Rest of your argument is sound, but I just feel 'someone' is unidiomatic. 'Street' version would be just 'anyone got a dollar?'

Comment: @Tetsujin: Both "someone" and "anyone" sound OK to me here. It might be a regional / sociolectal difference. (Not being a native speaker, my own ear tends to be tuned to a pretty fuzzy style of quasi-American "Internet English" by default.) If anything, using "anyone" perhaps suggests a slightly higher degree of desperation to my ear (as in "Does someone have a dollar? *Anyone?*"). I do agree that the "street" version definitely calls for "anyone", though.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - I'll agree it may be highly subjective/regional. To me someone sounds/feels wrong, but it's not something I'd get upset about if I was in conversation with even a native speaker from another area/country. Either would be OK, just one 'feels' better to my particular region/accent/etc